# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException: C# Multithreading & SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

We have a C# multi threaded (100 threads) program which reads the records from the DB and each thread picks up one record (one Entity Framework connection per thread) and update the a single DB table.

For first few minutes (5 minutes) the program works fine without exception then all of a sudden all threads starts throwing the below error messages.. After ~1 min everything will come back to normal stage.. I think the SQL Server is getting too many locks for a single DB table (might be trying to acquire table lock on that table) or too many connections to a single DB and closing all the connections..

I am unable to debug this, can some one help me in getting the following information,

1. Where does SQL Server 2012 store its logs?
2. Can we increase the log level to see why it throws an exception while saving the DB entity
3. How to get the number of locks per a table, different kind of locks (table lock, page lock, num row locks, etc) acquired by DB
4. Any other pointers to debug this issue.

FYI, I didn't find anything useful in sqlerror log got from this cmd (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName'))

Here is the stack trace of the exception

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException: An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.<Commit>b__c(DbTransaction t, DbTransactionInterceptionContext c)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.Commit(DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: Did you look at the inner exception as it suggested? What was there?

Comment: inner suggestion is commit failed.. It didn't say anything.. is there a way to debug these kind of failures in sql server?? like increasing the log level, etc?

Comment: Hi did you found a solution ? I'm experierncing the same issue but in my case just one record. Any updates could help me. Tks

Comment: Same issue here, any solution?

Comment: need to handle concurrency

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same sssue.If the threaded app is using same context object for all the threads we face these kind of issues.
Create separate context objects for each thread.You might be adding some more load on your RAM but it gives clarity about states of enities in Context.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
   ObjectContext oContext = new ObjectContext("MyConnection");
   Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      this.Update(item,oContext);
   });
   tasks.Add(t);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to an IO bottleneck.
Check your server RAM and disk usage.

Check the SQL Server Logs using

**Open SSMS -> Connect to Server -> Management -> SQL Server Logs -> Select the log range(Current/Archive) -> Check the logs**

Open the Windows event viewer and check for any warnings or errors.

In my case, one DB transaction log storage file was causing the issue due to a storage disk bottleneck. And in further analysis, we found that the bottleneck was due to the LSI_SAS inbox driver issue (a common RAID storage-related issue).

This was the SQL Server log message in my case.

```
SQL Server has encountered 7 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [D:\Databases\Running\MyDBName_log.ldf] in database id 11
```

If no logs are related to your issue, check the history of the SQL Job and Maintenance Plans and cross-check the time with your application error log.

Most of cases, the main victims of this error are tables with high-frequency data operations. So the query optimization will reduce the error frequency. But that won't be a permanent solution.

So use all the available data logs and track the issue.