# Commit failure Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The error (stack trace) we are receiving is the same as the one that is mentioned in below link but that solution does not seem to be correct and also does not seem to apply to our problem.

[System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException: C# Multithreading & SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501084/system-data-entity-infrastructure-commitfailedexception-c-sharp-multithreading)

We have APIs that are making some updates by saving the data in the SQL database.

This is when we are receiving timeout error same as the one that is in above link.

We have implemented this in Entity Framework and have been using the same from last 1 year. But, started facing issues recently (a month ago. And it seems it works when we retry the same operation after some time.

If you see the error, this (saveChanges) looks to be important.

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Apologies for the inconvenience caused. Should have mentioned all the details earlier. But was facing some indentation error while submitting above edits. New to the stack overflow. Let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: are you sure you installed database?

Comment: Please don't request "Please do not mark the question as duplicate". If it's a duplicate, it's not down to us to spoon-feed you the same information. I've removed this from your post.

Comment: The problem is clearly a timeout ("*The wait operation timed out*"). Without any code presented, or any suggestion of what operation is occurring when this happens, the only option is to recommend increasing the timeout on the context.

Comment: This isn't a question any more. It's kind of pointless to ask for help if you don't provide the facts when requested.

Comment: @spender Am I missing something or does it require more info?

Comment: I retracted my downvote in light of your changes. :) Is this Entity Framework Code-first or DB-first? There could be any number of issues causing this. First thing to find out is exactly what you expect to happen when `SaveChanges` is called. Is it possible that this might be committing a very large number of changes? Logging can help here. How is database CPU load/IO load? Are all the indexes set up correctly in your database? As tables grow, missing index issues can cause increasingly large role in long-running queries. Recent increase in users?

Comment: @spender Thank you :-) It is code first. Also, it does not seem index issue as it not taking any time to query and should be pretty fast in term of sql performance for queries. Seems to be Entity framework and hence C# code issue.  There is this below link in the error and hence seems to be drop from EF framework. [link] (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468). But, suggestions present at the link seems to be band-aid fixes. Any suggestions related to Entity framework would be appreciated as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the timeout is just a band-aid fix. If it really is a long running operation rather than just crappy code then look at putting it in a stored procedure in sql, fire and forget, and do a check back task to check the status completion until your client either loses interest in waiting or the task is done.